# Static IP with NetworkManager

Tags: networking, fedora, ip, networkmanager

I had my network config fail after upgrading from Fedora Server 26 to 27. The issue appears to have been due to the upgrade starting NetworkManager which in turn overwrote /etc/resolv.conf.

I got it working with the following minimal config:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network

DEVICE=enp37s0
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
PREFIX=24
IPADDR=192.168.0.100

cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.0.1

sudo systemctl restart network
```

First of all please let me know if my static IP config above could be improved. I had a lot more options before but it seems the more options I add the more issues I have. For example, after motherboard and CPU upgrade I lost network completely because I had HWADDR=xxxxx set which changed with new hardware.

My real question is what is the proper way to configure Static IP in Linux on a headless server. My current config above will break at the very least every time I upgrade to a new version of fedora. It seems that the Devs want users to use NetworkManager even on a Server distro. If that was not the case why would the upgrade process reinstall and re-enable NetworkManger when it is know that it will break static IP config. This is a server distro aafter all so static IP is pretty common and reliability paramount.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding the 300,000+ lines of C that is NetworkManger is very difficult on current RedHat systems.

I managed to make NetworkManager not mangle the DNS settings on Centos7 with the following in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifcfg-rh
dns=none
rc-manager=unmanaged
```